# wpf Datagrid Checkbox NotifyOnTargetUpdated not works

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid, inotifypropertychanged

My Class:

```
public class BarCode : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public string code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Visibility special1 { get; set; }
    public Visibility special2 { get; set; }
    private bool _x1, _x2;
    public bool x1
    {
        get
        {
            return _x1;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value && _x2)
                _x2 = false;
            _x1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("X1");
        }
    }
    public bool x2
    {
        get
        {
            return _x2;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value && _x1)
                _x1 = false;
            _x2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("X2");
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="X">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding special1}"></Setter>
          </Style>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=.x1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="X">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding special2}"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=.x2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I have two `CheckBoxes`. When the first is checked and I want to check the second one, then the first one shall de-check. But it is not updating. The check mark leaves only when I'm scrolling out of the visibility.

**EDIT: I changed the allocation _x1 = false and _x2 = false in the setters to x1 = false and x2 = false. Thanks [dkozl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1432140/dkozl) for your comment.**

```
public bool x1
{
    get
    {
        return _x1;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value && _x2)
            _x2 = false;
        x1 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("X1");
    }
}
public bool x2
{
    get
    {
        return _x2;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value && _x1)
            _x1 = false;
        x2 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("X2");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: your properties are `x1` and `x2` but you raise event for `X1` and `X2` (capital X) and property names are case sensitive. Also when you change x2 in x1 setter do it `x2 = false;` or event for `x2` as well

Comment: Thank you dkozl, it work when i chage the in setter x2 the allocation _x1 to x1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use TwoWay mode:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=.x1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"/>
```

If you just want one checkbox influence the status of the other then elementbinding would be helpfull as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-thinking your binding expression

you have this

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=.x2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"/>
```

When all you need it this

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=x2, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```